# Branch IO random App crash - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, branch.io

I am integrating Branch IO for App sharing in my application. I have implemented Share URL functionality with help of Branch with below code:

```
fun ShareApp(){
    val appShare = BranchUniversalObject()
            .setCanonicalIdentifier("app-share")
            .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentImageUrl(AppConstants.AppIconURL)
            .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)

    val lp = LinkProperties()
            .setChannel("facebook")
            .setFeature("sharing")

    val ss = ShareSheetStyle(this, appName, Message)
            .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
            .setSharingTitle("Share With")

    appShare.showShareSheet(this, lp, ss, object : Branch.BranchLinkShareListener {
        override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
        override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
        override fun onLinkShareResponse(sharedLink: String, sharedChannel: String, error: BranchError) {}
        override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {}
    })
}
```

Whenever I click on any channel say Whatsapp, sometimes it work and take me to whatsapp. But many times The channel is not getting selected and it gives me the below crash:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.eonian.reelo, PID: 10038
                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter error
                                                                  at com.eonian.reelo.ui.profile.profileSettings.ProfileSettingsActivity$ShareApp$1.onLinkShareResponse(ProfileSettingsActivity.kt:0)
                                                                  at io.branch.indexing.BranchUniversalObject$LinkShareListenerWrapper.onLinkShareResponse(BranchUniversalObject.java:980)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager.shareWithClient(ShareLinkManager.java:309)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager.access$700(ShareLinkManager.java:32)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager$3.onLinkCreate(ShareLinkManager.java:282)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ServerRequestCreateUrl.onUrlAvailable(ServerRequestCreateUrl.java:142)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.Branch.generateShortLinkInternal(Branch.java:2052)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.BranchUrlBuilder.generateUrlInternal(BranchUrlBuilder.java:140)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.BranchShortLinkBuilder.generateShortUrlInternal(BranchShortLinkBuilder.java:144)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager.invokeSharingClient(ShareLinkManager.java:278)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager.access$500(ShareLinkManager.java:32)
                                                                  at io.branch.referral.ShareLinkManager$1.onItemClick(ShareLinkManager.java:233)
                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3152)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4079)
                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3838)
                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9942)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2666)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2672)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2672)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2672)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:793)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
                                                                  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10162)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4314)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3914)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4007)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3888)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4064)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3914)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3888)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6257)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6196)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6157)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6360)
```

Mostly it end up getting crashed with channel name not getting selected. Is there any issue in Implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the crash, use this signature:

```
override fun onLinkShareResponse(
    sharedLink: String?, 
    sharedChannel: String?, 
    error: BranchError?)
```

Then you can inspect what's null instead of getting a low-level exception.

I saw the code on Branch's website, the Kotlin samples look broken. I don't think it makes sense that `error` is always non-null, even when there's no error. `sharedChannel` might be null in the case of an error.

Comment: Aaron from Branch here. @Siraj, can you give this a try? If this works to handle this case, we can surely update the documentation to ensure it works for Kotlin.

Comment: If you don't mind, you should also remove the `new` keyword from Kotlin samples. It doesn't exist in Kotlin.